# Kubernetes Ingress not properly routing traffic

Tags: nginx, networking, kubernetes, ingress, kubectl

I am trying to host a simple website using Kubernetes. I am trying to use a K8s deployment, service and an ingress to route the traffic from the external into the application running inside the pod.

The below is my YAML configuration file.

```
--- 
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: trojanwall-deployment
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: trojanwall
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: trojanwall
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: trojanwall
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: trojanwall
        image: arbabu/trojan-wall:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80 
--- 
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: trojanwall-service
  namespace: dev
spec:
selector:
  app: trojanwall
ports:
- name: http
  protocol: TCP
  port: 3000
  targetPort: 80
type: ClusterIP 

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: trojanwall-ingress
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "ec2-3-96-217-161.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/trojanwall"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: trojanwall-service
            port:
              number: 3000
```

The following is the resource status.

[image]

The expectation is that, when I run something like 'http://ec2-3-96-217-161.compute-1.amazonaws.com/trojanwall', I should be able to access my website. However, I am getting the following.

[image]

Does anyone know how to configure the ingress traffic properly?

Answer (score 1):

You need a loadbalancer, that is tipically provided by your cloud provider (which from that host name I guess it's AWS) which is very likely missing because you are also missing

```
ingressClassName: nginx
```

in spec section in your yaml file. This way the cloud load balancer can update the LoadBalancer ip address in the status section of nginx-ingress objects wich belong to that class.

The whole mechanis is in charge by the CCM (cloud controller manager), the k8s component which provides cloud specific features such as routing and service management (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/cloud-controller/#service-controller)

When you have your ingress binded correctly it will show something like this:

```
$ kubectl get ingress
NAME        CLASS   HOSTS           ADDRESS       PORTS     AGE   
myingress   nginx   myhostname.my   10.11.12.13   80, 443   6d9h
```

Here is (part of) my ingress manifest, for reference:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod   
  name: myingress
  namespace: myns
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: myhostname.my
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: myservice
            port:
              number: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```